# Get a list of numbers from stdin and display the closest to 0

Tags: python

I'm a beginner with Python and I try to get a list of numbers from stdin, then display the closest one to 0.

Here is what I did so far.

```
import sys
list = sys.stdin.readline().split()
print(min(list, abs))
```

But the output I got with this code is

```
<built-in function abs>
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Don't have variables in python named `list` so that it won't get confused with the "type" list.

Comment: You're comparing a `list` with a function (`abs`). You can't do this in Python 3 (`TypeError`) but in Python 2 you can make such comparisons and in this case the function is deemed smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python 2.x:

```
lis = raw_input("enter str").split()
```

python 3.x:

```
lis = input("enter str").split()
```

And fix `print(min(list, abs))` to:

```
print (abs(int(min(lis, key = lambda x: abs(int(x))))))
```

The shortest is:

```
print (abs(int(min(input("enter str").split(), key = lambda x: abs(int(x))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this was I looking for, except that I need to print the closest positive number to 0.
For example, if i have the following list : [42, -4, -4, 7]
I have to print 4, not -4

Comment: @omri_saadon I think the last example is wrong. The `lambda x: )` looks more like a `SyntaxError` (or a smiley).

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks for noticing. fixed that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `key`-argument for [`min`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) is keyword-only so you need to pass it in like this:

```
min(lst, key=abs)
```

Otherwise it tries to check if the `lst < abs` which compares a list to a function, which leads to "*unexpected*" results (the function is smaller!).

However you need to convert the items to integers (or [float](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float)s?) as well (otherwise `abs` would be applied to strings), for example with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

```
lst = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())  # or float instead of "int" if you expect decimals
```

---

You mentioned that you're only interested in the smallest positive number, in that case you can use:

```
lst = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())  # identical
positives = filter(lambda x: x >= 0, lst)     # remove numbers below 0
min(positives)
```

or all in one line:

```
min(int(item) for item in sys.stdin.readline().split() if int(item) >= 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I now understand why my code didn't have worked.

Comment: @ChrisProlls I just saw that you're interested in the smallest positive number so I added an approach that works that way as well. :)

Comment: It's not exactly I have to do ;)
Maybe I didn't explained it clearly.


I have to print the closest number to zero. But if there is two matches, like -4 & 4, I have to chose the positive one !


I have already solved my problem, but if you have another solution, I'm up to learn it. Know multiples approaches  for solving a problem is always a good thing.